# What is min and max in $\delta -\epsilon$ proof?

Tags: calculus, notation, definition

So I've been going through limit proofs and I came across the definition of $MIN$ and $MAX$  I saw a definition say that $MAX(a,b)$ picks the smaller of the 2 numbers my question is what if $a =b$ what does max return?

For example what does $max(2,2)$ equal?.

This is probably a silly question but i just want to be certain on definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Max}{Max} \Max(a,b)$ returns the maximum of $a$ and $b$. That is

$\Max(a,b)=a$ if $a>b$.

$\Max(a,b)=b$ if $a<b$.

And finally...

$\Max(a,b)=a=b$ (it doesn't matter, they are the same), if $a=b$.

Then $\Max(2,2)=2$.